# What's the algebra behind this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you prove this expression true?

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2}^n}\right)^4=\frac{n^2}{4^n}$$

My issue is with the denominator being $4^n$ and not $2^{2n}$.

Thank You.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $4^n=2^{2n}$!!!

Comment: Thank you, I mainly wanted to test the functionality of this site. I registered about 15 minutes ago. 

I'll definitely be using this site more often!

Comment: Will help you to learn a little bit of [LaTex](http://www.latex-project.org/). Also, if your comment is directed at a specific user, and you want it to get that user's attention, then you should start the comment with `@` followed by the alias of the user.

Comment: see the "power of a power" rule. http://mathontrack.comze.com/exponentials2.html

Comment: @barakmanos That's a lot of factorials.

Comment: @G.Bach: Haha, didn't realize that :)

Comment: @Kosta You recieved a lot of answers for your question, and all of them are correct.  Did they answer your question? If so, then it is the way of this site to accept the answer that best answers your question. If not, then it is polite to explain (in comments) Why an answer is not what you were looking for. It is not polite to just ignore your question once you asked it and got an answer to it.

Comment: @5xum I wasn't aware of this, I'll be more mindful with my future posts. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt 2^n}\right)^4=\left(\frac{n^{1/2}}{2^{n/2}}\right)^4=\frac{n^{4/2}}{2^{4n/2}}=\frac{n^2}{2^{2n}}=\frac{n^2}{(2^2)^n}=\frac{n^2}{4^n}$$

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt{2}^n=(2^\frac{1}{2})^n=2^{\frac{n}{2}}$  and so $(\sqrt{2}^n)^4=(2^\frac{n}{2})^4=2^{4\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}=2^{2n}=(2^2)^n=4^n$.

Answer (score 2):

You have $4^n$. Since $4 = 2^2$, this is $(2^2)^n$. And since in general
$$
(a^b)^c = (a^b)(a^b) \ldots (a^b) \text{($c$ times) } = a^{bc}
$$
you get 
$$
4^n = (2^2)^n = 2^{2n}.
$$